# Is it a best practice to use one key to register multiple objects?

Tags: php, redis

I am working on a system where I need to cache products, user carts, etc. For example, for products, I created a key named productCategory you can see the image below then I added fields with the name of each category and then I encoded the data as json.

I want to ask if I made the right choice, if I will not have issues in terms of performance, data access, etc.

[Key sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEA4t.png)

Comment: Did you consider using the Redis Module https://redisjson.io?

Comment: I am assuming these products are unique? If they are then you should be using uniq identifiers to avoid overriding other cached objects. It looks like you have some sort of unique id in the response that starts the json. Maybe use that?

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. @GuyKorland I encode object with php build-in json_encode and send it to redis. To edit, I use json_decode and make modifications and then save them to redis. Do you think it would be more efficient to use redisjson?

Comment: @Vinnie, Each product is identified with its SKU code which is unique, when I decode the json string, the SKU is the key to the php array.

Thank you again!

Comment: Hugues it might be much more efficient since you won't have to read the a JSON when you only want to update it

Comment: @GuyKorland thank you! I really appreciate your help, I will make some changes to adapt my code.